# Parsing an HTML file with selectorgadget.com

Tags: python, css, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-content-extraction

How can I use beautiful soup and [selectorgadget](http://selectorgadget.com) to scrape a website. For example I have a website - [(a newegg product)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115017) and I would like my script to return all of the specifications of that product (click on SPECIFICATIONS) by this I mean - Intel, Desktop, ......, 2.4GHz, 1066Mhz, ...... , 3 years limited.

After using selectorgadget I get the string- 
.desc

How do I use this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the page, I can see that the specifications are placed in a div with the ID pcraSpecs:

```
<div id="pcraSpecs">
  <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
  <TABLE cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="specification">
    <TR>
      <TD colspan="2" class="title">Model</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD class="name">Brand</TD>
      <TD class="desc"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(neg_specification_newline('Intel'));</script></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD class="name">Processors Type</TD>
      <TD class="desc"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(neg_specification_newline('Desktop'));</script></TD>    
    </TR>
    ...
  </TABLE>
</div>
```

desc is the class of the table cells.

What you want to do is to extract the contents of this table.

`soup.find(id="pcraSpecs").findAll("td")` should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Feedity - http://feedity.com for creating a custom RSS feed from any webpage.